# Cannot pause looping movie because of bugs in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotifications

I set up the movie player like this:

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:@"whatever.mp4"];
    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.container.bounds;
    self.moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.container addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object: self.moviePlayer];
```

The notification is necessary to keep the player looping, since repeatMode is pretty much useless (the video will repeat once or twice, maybe a few times depending on the price of rice in China, then stop). So to keep the video looping you have to do this:

```
- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note {
    if (note.object == self.moviePlayer) {
        NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
            [self.moviePlayer play];
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I need to be able to pause the video. For some reason a call to

```
    [self.moviePlayer pause];
```

results in the notification getting fired with reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded even though the documentation clearly states this:

```
Constants
MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded
The end of the movie was reached.
Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
Declared in MPMoviePlayerController.h.
```

The end of the movie was not reached. I just called pause:. So the notification gets fired and thus the movie gets played again, negating the pause action.

So you can see the problem. How can I successfully pause a looping video?

Comment: why not track whether the notification was triggered by pause button or loop ended using a BOOL variable?

Comment: How? Like I said whether the video ends or pause is called the reason comes back as MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a BOOL in your class and initialize it to NO,

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isTriggeredByPause;
```

before calling

```
[self.moviePlayer pause];
```

set its value,

```
self.isTriggeredByPause = YES;
```

in your method check for it,

```
 (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note {
if (note.object == self.moviePlayer) {
    NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
if(!self.isTriggeredByPause)
{
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
}
}
}
```

Modify value of self.isTriggeredByPause on manual play too, or loop won't work.